# Microsoft Graph API: how to get access token without browser

Tags: sharepoint, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to upload a given file to Sharepoint. I'm using the Microsoft Graph API.

The [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/get-started/rest) follows this workflow:

```
1. If no token, redirect the user to the Microsoft signin page.
2. The user is then redirected to the application, with an access token
3. Use access token to have an authorization bearer
4. Do what you gotta do...
```

My problem is the sign-in part. I don't want my users to be redirected to the Microsoft signin page. I want my application to connect and get the access token in the background (with cURL or whatever).

How can I do that? Why is the "open in browser" necessary?

I tried to replicate the sign-in process, but all I get back is the HTML response from the signin page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application act as a single-tenant service or daemon app.

The documentation about this scenario is here : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/app_only

- The application must be registered in the AzureAD directory corresponding to the Office365 tenant
- A first request is made by passing the application unique identifier and secret key as registered in the directory. This request returns an access token

The access token can now be used in the *Authorization* header of the following request to the Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. It was just right there in front of me!

Comment: Guys I'm having the same problem but after following documents I can see that the API requires grant_type which must be set to client_credentials, so how am I supposed to populate this value?! here's the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#service-to-service-access-token-request

Answer (score 1):

This method (of using Client ID and Secret) works well but there are other ways which may be better suited for similar scenarios.

The one major thing which is missing in access token generated this way is a **user**, meaning the token only contains the identity of the OAuth **application** (client) which called it but is not associated with any user for the request.

This could have a couple of implications:

- Since the token is not associated with a specific user you will not know who performed the operation. In your example, you would not know who uploaded the file (and other similar information may be missing).
- Access token without users will not work at all for some methods. For those, you need a **delegated token**.

Creating a delegated token requires some effort, if you are interested you can find the details in my article:

[Getting Access Token for Microsoft Graph Using OAuth REST API](http://codematters.tech/getting-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-using-oauth-rest-api/)

Comment: Looks like your article could have solved my problem. But the article is not there anymore

Comment: Looks like the link has moved to [dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/getting-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-using-oau).   [Wayback Machine link](https://web.archive.org/web/20211029021003/https://dzone.com/articles/getting-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-using-oau)